Relationship between uniform contintuity and Lipschitz continuity for monotone functions
I am self studying real analysis and I am investigating on the relationship between uniform continuity and Lipschitz continuity.
More precisely, I wanted to construct an example of a function $f$ defined on some unbounded interval such as $I=[a,+\infty)$, $a\in \mathbb R$, that is uniformly continuous, monotone, and not Lipschitz continuous in any neighborhood of $+\infty$, but I got stuck.
If the function is differentiable in $I$, then the derivative must be unbounded, for otherwise Lipschitz continuity would follow immediately. At the same time I have to guarantee that $f(x) = O(x)$ for $x\to +\infty$, in order not to loose uniform continuity. So I assume $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f'(x)$ must not exist. I tried to create 'bumps' in the derivative but could not find a way to do so and preserve uniform continuity.
I know that, since $I$ is a convex set, $f$ must be almost Lipschitz, i.e. for every $\eta>0$, there exists $M_\eta>0$ such that $$|f(y)-f(x)| \leq M_\eta |y-x| + \eta\tag{1}\label{1}$$
for all $x,y$ in $I$.
QUESTIONS

Can you give me some hint on how to create such an example, assuming it is possible?
Does \eqref{1} imply that such function must be asymptotically equivalent to a Lipschitz continuous function?
In case it is not, any suggestion on the path to prove it is very welcome.
What happens if the function is not differentiable? I know monotonicity forces the set of points where the function is not differentiable to have measure $0$. Does this help in the process of finding an example/proving the impossibility of such a situation?


Your function needs not be equivalent to a lipschitz function at infinity. Consider the function $f$ such that for $x\in [n,n+1)$ we have $f(x)=n+\sqrt{x-n}$. This function is increasing, uniformly continuous, but not lipschitz continuous on any $[a,\infty)$.

@SeverinSchraven Thanks for your help. This function does satifsy the conditions I was looking for. As for my question 2., (which as a matter of fact I added as a later edit): the example you give is $x\leq f(x) \leq x+1/4$ so it is in fact $f(x)\sim x$ for $x\to +\infty$; correct?

Yes, that is correct. You could probably also upgrade my counterexample to a differentiable one if you wanted to (essentially smooth out the above example on $[n-1/n, n+1/n]$ via polynomial interpolation), though I have not checked the details.

@SeverinSchraven indeed. After posting the question I also came up with $f(x) = 1-2^n$ for $n=0,1,2\dots$, which can be mollified as to make it continuous and differentiable. It has a limit for $x\to +\infty$ so it is uniformly continuous. Why you say $f$ need not be asymptotically equivalent to a Lipschitz function? Do you have some examples in mind?

That is because my brain converted the question to "is the function equal to a lipschitz one outside of any compact domain?" (which is false as per my example). Your question is more subtle and I do not know the answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Thanks. I will keep digging into that.

@SeverinSchraven, if you sample the original function say $f(n\delta)$ ($n=0,1,2\dots$), where $\delta$ is the number that guarantees $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \varepsilon$ whenever $|x-y|\leq \delta$, then you connect those points with a straight line and mollify the result, you get a monotone differentiable Lipschitz function, that should be asympotically equivalent to $f$ since the difference with it is "under control"...?

Now you are asking multiple questions, which is against MSE rules. I no longer understand what is it that you really want to know.

The standard example is $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, $x\ge 0$. It is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ by compactness of this interval. It is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$ because it has bounded derivative on this interval. It is clearly strictly increasing. But it is not Lipschitz at $0$ (which is a good and elementary exercise to work out by considering the ratios $f(x)/x$).

Thanks for help! I was actually looking for an example where the function is not Lipschitz in any interval $[a,+\infty)$, no matter how large you take $a$. But as @SeverinSchraven shows, we can in fact use $\sqrt x$ to build up such an instance.

@dfnu It that is the case, then you might wish to update your question.

Done, thank you for pointing it out.

Sorry for the multiple questions. I added number 2. as an edit a little time after I first posted the question. I thought it could be interesting as an additional observation, and at the time noone had given any feedback yet. I apologize for the confusion.

Many thanks to Moishe Kohan and Severin Schraven for their useful answers and comments.
As for my question number 2. I came up with a possible answer myself.
I think one can state in general that if $f$ is uniformly continuous in $[a,+\infty)$, then, for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a Lipschitz continuous function $f_\varepsilon(x)$ such that
$$|f(x)-f_\varepsilon(x)|\leq \varepsilon,$$
for all $x\in [a,+\infty)$.
Since the function $f$ is almost Lipschitz, for every $\eta >0$ we can find $M_\eta >0$ such that
$$|f(y)-f(x)|\leq M_\eta|y-x| + \eta.$$
Select $\eta = \varepsilon/4$, and fix $\Delta = \varepsilon/4M_\varepsilon$. Sample then $f$ at points $a,a+\Delta,a+2\Delta\dots$, and let $f_\varepsilon$ be the piecewise linear function connecting the points $P_n(a+n\Delta,f(a+n\Delta))$ on the graph of $f$.

Then, for $a+n\Delta \leq x\leq a+(n+1)\Delta$ we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
|f(x)-f_\varepsilon(x)| &\leq& \left|f(x)-f\left(a+n\Delta\right)\right|\\
&&+ \left|f\left(a+n\Delta\right)-f_\varepsilon(x)\right|\\
&\leq& \frac{\varepsilon}2 + \left|f\left(a+n\Delta\right)-f\left(a+(n+1)\Delta\right)\right|\\
&\leq \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
The maximum slope of the line segments is $2M_{\varepsilon/4}$, so that $f_\varepsilon$ is Lipschitz continuous.
If $f$ is monotone $f_\varepsilon$ is also monotone.
